# Who actually mounts the file system and creates directories like /bin, /dev, /etc

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, mount, init

I have a really basic doubt, which part creates all these directories, where is this configuration of creating directories stored while installing a new OS?

What is the order in which these directories are created? Are they created after `/boot` has been mounted by the kernel, by which part of the kernel?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what directories. If you mean the ones from the title, please include them in the actual question, but more importantly, note that `/dev/` is a completely different thing to `/bin` but neither is created on boot. The _contents_ of `/dev/` and `/proc` and `/sys` are created on boot or while the system is working, but not the directories themselves. And are you asking about system installation or normal system use? Basically, please [edit] your question and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBUPc0aO5lw) does an OK job of explaining the whole boot process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The root filesystem** is mounted first (readonly) **at bootime**, as your bootlog could tell you :

```
[kernel] [    2.242830] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 8:24.
```

It will then be remounted **at init time** :

```
[kernel] [    2.266181] Run /sbin/init as init process
...
[kernel] [    6.882156] EXT4-fs (sdb8): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[kernel] [    6.882160] ext4 filesystem being remounted at /
```

From there incidentally **populating** with (at the very least) all standard base directories (/bin, /usr, /dev, /etc…) possibly empty, possibly serving as mountpoints on which, still as part of the init process…

**other disk filesystems** will be mounted following `/etc/fstab` directives :

```
[kernel] [    7.155270] EXT4-fs (sdb9): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: data=writeback,commit=120
[kernel] [    7.155274] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /var
[kernel] [    7.222851] EXT4-fs (sdb10): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: data=writeback
[kernel] [    7.222855] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /home
```

This as a successful result of some init service (e.g. *localmount* in openrc), incidentally populating every standard directory of any *x sytem as well as possibly… even more.

BTW, since [the kernel does not need `/boot` filesystem it might well never be mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698017/unmount-boot-after-booting/698033#698033). It just can be, at init time, depending on  `/etc/fstab` entries.

**Network File Systems** **can** (v.g. not necessarily) be mounted as well **at init time**, in a way depending on the init system (e.g. *netmount* service in openrc) taking care network services will have been successfully launched before as an obvious prerequisite.

***Special* file systems** (procfs / sysfs / configfs or other *virtual*? *pseudo*? filesystems presenting non-file elements of an operating system as files) will, depending on appropriate CONFIG_* kernel tuneables be mounted **at init time**, depending on the init system (e.g. execution of `/lib/rc/sh/init.sh` for openrc) and being consequently automomagically **populated**.

**Temporary File Systems** (data is stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device) can also be mounted **at init time** following directives found in `/etc/fstab` e.g.

```
tmpfs  /tmp  tmpfs   rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=4G,mode=1777
```

**/dev particular case :**

The `/dev` directory exists as per `/` mount together with two nodes the kernel needs at early boot time : `/dev/console` and `/dev/null`.
The kernel will add new nodes into `/dev` directory **at boot time** following devices' enumeration.
If the kernel is configured to enable temporary file systems, the nodes won't be created in the root partition :
The kernel will first mount an empty temporary file system on the `/dev` directory, overlaying its content.

```
[kernel] [    2.262470] devtmpfs: mounted
```

Hence allowing the devices to be created dynamically into that filesystem as they are detected (or accessed).

Of course, Linux being a plug&play OS, the population is subject to change at runtime.